# Lists.asmx requiring authentication

Tags: web-services, iis, soap

I always thougth the url `http://server/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` is open ie. dont need authentication.

But recently i installed sharepoint server 2010 in one of my clients machine and put it on public.
But when i hit the URL in the browser i demanded authentication.

This this is causing problem in my middleware code.
Could some one tell me what actually it is.

Is it demanding sharepoint authentication or IIS or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a variety of things but the first thing I'd check is what zone IE thinks `http://server/` is in.  If it is the Internet Zone or Trusted Sites then it will prompt for authentication.  You may have to add it to the Intranet Zone in order to get it to pass Windows Credentials through to SharePoint.  This is in IE under Tools-Internet Options-Security.

If this is a larger corporate customer then chances are that there is already a wildcard inclusion in the Intranet zone along the lines of "*.company.com" in which case, the better solution would be to use a FQDN for your new server of "`http://server.company.com`".  That way you don't have to mess with every current and future installation of IE in the company.